# How does system() affect the stack in x64 linux?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow

I'm reading through Jon Erickson's excellent book "Hacking: the Art of Exploitation" and am trying to understand his exposition of buffer overflows. The book does seem a bit dated; in his examples he is running x86 linux, and I am having trouble replicating results on x64 (I do know that greater stack protection has been added in recent years). In particular I am struggling to replicate his `exploit_notesearch.c` program.

Early in the book he demonstrated a program `notesearch.c` that runs suid root and has the following initial lines, after library inclusions and function declarations:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int userid, printing=1, fd;
    char searchstring[100];

    if(argc>1)
        strcpy(searchstring, argv[1]);
    else
        searchstring[0]=0;
...
```

Now, Erickson later demonstrates an exploit for this program, called `exploit_notesearch.c`, the skeleton of which is:

```
char shellcode[]=
"\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\x99\xb0\xa4\xcd\x80\x6a"
"\x0b\x58\x51\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69"
"\x6e\x89\xe3\x51\x89\xe2\x53\x89\xe1\xcd\x80";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned int i, *ptr, ret, offset=170;
    char *command, *buffer;
...
    if(argc>1)
        offset=atoi(argv[1]);
    ret=(unsigned int) &i-offset;
...
    system(command);
    free(command);
}
```

The areas that I've elided are just copying the right data into `command`, starting with writing `"./notesearch '"`, then injecting 60 `NOP` bytes, then injecting the data held in `shellcode`, and then filling the rest of the allocated memory with the address `ret` and ending the string with `'`.

As I understand it, the idea of the exploit should be as follows. Upon executing the line `system(command)`, the system will push a new stack frame for the `main` function of `notesearch` onto the stack. At the bottom of this stack frame is the address that `EIP` should return to upon completing the main function, and somewhere in the middle is space allocated for the `searchstring` buffer. `ret` is meant to approximate the start of the space allocated for `searchstring`,  which we overwrite with `NOP` instructions (as a fudge factor), the shellcode (which upon execution opens a root shell), and then dozens of copies of the address `ret` to ensure that we will overwrite the return address for `EIP`. The system executes `main` as normal, but then, rather than returning to an address in the code of `exploit_notesearch`, instead returns to the address `ret`, and proceeds the execute the shellcode as desired. The idea behind defining `ret` is that `i` lives somewhere in the stack frame directly above the stack frame for the `main` function of `notesearch.c`, so `searchstring` should not live too far away from `i`, and hence by experimenting with different offsets we should be able to find one that works. (The `NOP` sled means we do not have to be completely precise.)

I think I have mostly understood this correctly, but there a few problems. The principal one is that my understanding of how `system()` works is based on guesswork, as Erickson does not detail how it works. To understand what's going on I've tried to rewrite this program to be compatible with x64 linux, making the following changes:

- replacing the shellcode given by Erickson with shellcode written for x64
- changing `i`, `ret`, and `offset` to unsigned long ints and changing the increment of `i` in the `for` loop to `8`, to account for larger memory addresses
- compiling both `notesearch.c` and `exploit_notesearch.c` with the `-fno-stack-protector` flag

However, this has not worked at all, so for debugging I added a line to `notesearch.c` that prints the address `searchstring` and a line to `exploit_notesearch.c` that prints the address `ret`. Upon running `./exploit_notesearch` several times I got strange results:

```
trial 1:
ret:          0x7ffdc21f25ce
searchstring: 0x7ffee3c209a0

trial 2:
ret:          0x7fff6115703e
searchstring: 0x7ffd1233afb0

trial 3:
ret:          0x7ffeab00781e
searchstring: 0x7fff3c8a8760
```

So, what's going on here? It seems like calling `system()` changes the stack in really unpredictable ways, sometimes putting the new stack frame below the old one and sometimes putting it above. Debugging with `gdb` did not help, as it seems the whole call of `system()` is bundled up into a single line `call   0x555555554710 <system@plt>`, which did not provide any insight.

So, my main questions are these:

- how do shell commands called with `system()` interact with the stack?
- is this done differently in x64 linux than it was in x86, or have I really misunderstood the code written by Erickson?
- is there a way to disable these security measures on x64 linux when compiling, so that I can follow along with Erickson's code while I am learning?

Apologies for the long-winded question and thanks in advance.

---

**Edit: Per the suggestion of Jester below I have disabled ASLR and now the program works correctly. As a follow-up question then, does anyone have any references for understanding ASLR? Cheers!**

Comment: `ret` and `searchstring` are in different processes. Their addresses are not related in any way especially with stack being randomized. You can try turning ASLR off but even that might leave stack randomized.

Comment: `system()` is just an ordinary function, it uses the stack the same way that calling any other function does.

Comment: @Jester thanks so much; two questions. First, do you have references for understanding processes and ASLR? I have not heard those terms before. Second, were those protections around in 2008? And if not how was Erickson's code supposed to work? Thanks again!

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, to clarify – I don't mean where the stack frame for `system()` goes, but where the stack frame for a shell command called using `system()` goes

Comment: Have edited for clarity

Comment: I think you need tp get a book more relevant to the x64 world we have today.

Comment: @barny that makes sense; do you know of any good references?

Comment: Sorry no - by the nature of the topic and the extreme relevance of security, these days exploits are (I hope!) often fixed before any information is publicly available. You might have to loiter in darker corners of the internet to stand any chance of being able to actually try out an exploit. No I don’t know any darker corners :-o

Comment: @barny no worries, thanks so much all the same!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Upon executing the line `system(command)`, the system will push a new stack frame for the main function of `notesearch` onto the stack

No. That's completely wrong. `system(xxx)` is a convenient library wrapper for the `execve` syscall, which does a `fork` first to run the process as a child:

```
system("xxx");

// Roughly equivalent to:

int wstatus;
pid_t child = fork();

if (child == -1) {
    return -1;
} else if (child == 0) {
    execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh", "-c", "xxx"], envp); // execute shell in child
} else {
    waitpid(child, &wstatus, 0); // wait for child to complete in parent
    return WEXITSTATUS(wstatus);
}
```

It starts a new shell that executes the program (or command[s]) you pass as argument. When you do this, a new child that is equal to the parent is created by `fork`, and then, in the child, the program is *wiped away* from the operating system, and replaced with the new one by `execve`. A new stack is created, and the new program starts.

> how does `system()` interact with the stack?

It doesn't interact in any particular way, it's just a normal library function like I said above. When the `execve` syscall is executed, the forked clone of this process is replaced by the kernel with a freshly-initialized process its own virtual address space (doing ASLR for it separately).  Then it `wait`s for that shell process to exit.  None of this has any effect on the address-space of the process that called `system()`.

> is this done differently in x64 linux than it was in x86, or have I really misunderstood the code written by Erickson?

You definitely have misunderstood the code. What that `system()` is doing is simply running the vulnerable program with a precisely crafted `argv[1]` to cause a buffer overflow and overwrite the return address of the `main()` function leading to `RIP` overwrite and control of the execution.

> It seems like calling `system()` changes the stack in really unpredictable ways, sometimes putting the new stack frame below the old one and sometimes putting it above.

Of course, since `system()` merely creates a new process with `execve`.

> is there a way to disable these security measures on x64 linux when compiling, so that I can follow along with Erickson's code while I am learning?

Yes, you can disable **[ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)** to stop the kernel from randomizing the position of the stack:

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0
```

`gdb` should already do this for you but only if the process is started from inside `gdb`.

Comment: Actually `system` is a wrapper for `fork`+`exec` so the original process is not wiped away :)

Comment: It's not strictly `glibc`. Any POSIX system [will have it as `fork`/`exec`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html).

Comment: @S.S.Anne true, I'm too used to assume `glibc` everywhere. Thanks.

Comment: In other words, `exploit_notesearch` isn't really doing anything especially sneaky; the entire hack is the sequence of bytes to give to `notesearch` on the command-line. In theory, you could run the hack straight from a shell by pasting in the correct sequence of characters, many of which are non-ASCII. That would just be a huge pain and difficult to double-check; hence the extra program to do it for you.

Comment: Thank you so much, this mostly makes sense. Just to clarify a few points about forking; when a program forks with ASLR disabled, does this mean the child process' memory segments will have the same addresses as the parent process'? How does this work without the two of them overwriting each other?

Comment: And second, in general, what is the incentive to use `system` rather than `execve` directly? Thanks so much again

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom after fork the child is *identical* to the parent. Even with ASLR enabled. It's `execve()` that changes everything executing a new process. In general, using `system()` is way simpler and allows to check the return value of the child, while `execve()` (if successful) would just replace the running process and never return.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes perfect sense. Thank you so much again!